# When i Check the Checkbox how do I change that specific row style? C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

So i got this gridview on ASP.NET, it is about a gmail client, i made a template field with a check box that is for select several message at the same time, but first when you select a message i want to change the row background color, I already have my CSS but i dont know how to trigger the action or how to know what row was selected in the code. Here is the template of my grid:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="inboxGrid" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="inbox" ShowHeader="false" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="24" CssClass="check"/>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="from" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" 
                    Text = '<%# Eval("From") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="subject" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="date" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFecha" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fecha") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <RowStyle CssClass="inbox"/>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: are you ok with using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using JQuery

Provided you add a **CssClass** named **chk** to **asp:checkbox**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" CssClass="chk" />
```

Here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".chk :checkbox").live("click", function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color", this.checked ? "#0000FF" : "");
        });
    });
```

Comment: This worked great, just that I still need to store the row index for later actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" OnClick="changeCss(this.id);" />
```

You can use `toggleClass('CssClassName')` to toggle the class on checkbox clicks:

```
function changeCss(ctrlId){
    $(ctrlId).parent().parent().toggleClass('check');
}
```

The hierarchy is tr > td > checkbox, we go reverse to change the css of tr/row.